# How to check Apache RewriteRule regex performance - speed? Is there any tool for that?

Tags: regex, performance, apache, mod-rewrite

For easy example it is easy understandable that rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,8})$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

is faster than

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But is there any way to check and compare its (Apache RewriteRule regex) correct performance?

Answer (score 4):

Apache regex seems to be [derived from PCRE](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/util_pcre.c) so you can probably use `pcretest` to benchmark and get a clue how they perform.

Here are the results when timing the two expressions using one million test matches and three different test inputs. Outputting is average execution time for each match.

```
$ pcretest -tm 1000000 -q
  re> /^([a-z]{2,8})$/
data> a
Execute time 0.0002 milliseconds
No match
data> aaaaaaaa
Execute time 0.0003 milliseconds
 0: aaaaaaaa
 1: aaaaaaaa
data> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Execute time 0.0006 milliseconds
No match
data>
```

---

```
$ pcretest -tm 1000000 -q
  re> /^(.*)$/
data> a
Execute time 0.0003 milliseconds
 0: a
 1: a
data> aaaaaaaa
Execute time 0.0003 milliseconds
 0: aaaaaaaa
 1: aaaaaaaa
data> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Execute time 0.0005 milliseconds
 0: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 1: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
data>
```

They seem to have similar execution times, around 2-3 million matches per second on my test machine. But the real questions is, why do you suspect that the matching time for the rewrite rules are a problem?